# Undefined control sequence \filename@base when including figures using overpic

Tags: floats, overpic

UPDATE: I've just updated the code to put a full example of the code generating the error messages.

UPDATE2: I tried to change the name of figure files (without underscores) but I still have the issue.

In short, I am experiencing two issues when trying to include a figure using the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{overpic}

\title{\bf An Example of Book Class}
\author{for \LaTeX\ Class}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\mainmatter
\part{A Part Heading}
\chapter{A Main Heading}

\begin{figure}[!H]
    % trim={<left> <lower> <right> <upper>}
    \begin{overpic}{
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, trim=95 20 95 30]{figures/file1.eps}}
        \put(-500,220){\includegraphics[scale=0.72, trim=35 10 35 12]{figures/file2.eps}}
    \end{overpic}
    \caption{hi.}
    \label{fig:displacement-errors}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Error messages i am getting are:

```
[Error(s)]
E: exbook.tex:17    LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.
E: exbook.tex:26    Undefined control sequence \filename@base.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `\detokenize` is not supposed to be used in filenames, only when typesetting the underscores. Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: you can never use `!` and `H` together and `H` does not work (as far as I know) with sidewaysfigure

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks you are right, it works when using the H without the "!" overriding parameter.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? If pdfTeX, remove the `.eps` extensions. Underscores in filenames have never been a problem for me and your errors don't mention them.

Comment: @cfr  I use Texlive2017 on windows. and I am using pdfLaTeX. I am trying without `.eps` extension and getting a very similar error message: 
`! Undefined control sequence.
\filename@simple ...#2\\}\fi \edef \filename@base 
                                                  {#1}
l.20 ...xtwidth, trim=95 20 95 30]{figures/file1}}
?`
If I use the pdfTeX compiler i get the following error message: 
`! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  [11pt]{book}`

Comment: I meant `pdflatex` unless you specify the format when calling `pdftex`. But pdfTeX is the engine.

Comment: If I delete `!`, add `demo` to the class options and compile your code with `pdflatex`, it works fine. (I added `demo` since I obviously don't have the EPS files.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself!
There is an error using the overpic instructions, hereafter the right code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{overpic}[width=1\textwidth, trim=95 20 95 30]{figures/file1.eps}
    \put(-500,220){\includegraphics[scale=0.72, trim=35 10 35 12]{figures/file2.eps}}
    \end{overpic}
    \caption{hi.}
    \label{fig:displacement-errors}
\end{figure}
```

There is no includegraphics to include the first graphic.
Thanks for all commenters that tried to help :)